# Remote lookup of ejb fails when initial context is cached

Tags: caching, ejb, websphere, lookup

I have a situation where in my web layer, I do a remote EJB lookup and cache the initial context. Now the remote EJB is deployed in a WAS cluster. so if the remote ejb is deployed across server1,server2 and server3 and let us say the first time, the initial context pointing to server1 is cached.

After this server1 goes down but other servers are still up. But because the initial context is cached, the ejb calls fail.

Now the simple solution is to remove the cache and do a fresh lookup every time. But that would degrade performance. Is there a way to have the best of both worlds here...reliability and also performance?

Comment: You have separate web and EJB servers.  How does the web server create the InitialContext()?  If you bootstrap against the local server and look up a cluster context, then the resulting Context should be WLM'ed across all the cluster members.

Comment: While creating the InitialContext, we supply the provider_url and the provider_url is a comma separated string of the hostnames deployed in the cluster. How do you create a 'cluster context'? and also what is WLM?

Comment: If you're already specifying a comma-delimited list of hosts/posts, then I think your InitialContext should already be failing over.  Otherwise, I think you could do `new InitialContext().lookup("cell/clusters/xyz")`, which I think is the same as specifying all the hosts/ports of servers in the cluster.  WLM is work-load management, the technology that does routing/failover.

Comment: The failover mechanism is in effect at the time of creation of initilacontext. after initial context is created and cached, if we continue to use the context in the cache, we cannot take advantage of failover mechanism. So if new InitialContext() returns a cached initial context that has a bad connection, then the lookup will fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The list of bootstrap servers in the `corbaloc:` provider URL is only used when the `InitialContext` is constructed. During the construction of the context, the client gets a list of servers that can answer lookups for that context, and only that list is used afterwards. If the bootstrap servers in the provider URL are cluster members, then the `InitialContext` will continue to work as long as at least one cluster member is running. Therefore the `InitialContext` can be safely cached.

Note that things are different if the bootstrap servers in the provider URL are not cluster members, but node agents. In that case, the `InitialContext` referes to a context specific to a single node agent and lookups will fail when that node agent is down. This is the case even if multiple node agents are specified in the provider URL: one of the node agents is chosen during construction of the `InitialContext` and the selection will not change afterwards.

Comment: Cluster members and node agents are not same?When the provider_url is a comma separated list of hostnames and port numbers, how to tell if they are cluster members or node agents?

Comment: By identifying the process that is listening on the port. You can either do that at the system level (e.g. using `netstat -ltnp`) or by checking the ports in the WebSphere admin console.